# Why is data missing when I write to a python subprocess stdin pipe?

Tags: python, bash, pipe, subprocess

My python code looks like this:

```
def test():
    pipe = sp.Popen( ["test.sh"], stdin=sp.PIPE)
    data = "".join([chr((s)%17) for s in range(0,33)])
    os.write(pipe.stdin.fileno(), data)
    pipe.stdin.write("endoffile")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

It calls the following simple bash shell script which simply writes stdin to a file (script is called test.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
VALUE=$(cat)

echo "$VALUE" >> /tmp/test.txt
```

When I run the python code I expect test.txt to contain the values 0x01..0x10 two times, and after that the string "endoffile"

However here's a hexdump of the file:

```
0000000: 0102 0304 0506 0708 090a 0b0c 0d0e 0f10  ................
0000010: 0102 0304 0506 0708 090a 0b0c 0d0e 0f65  ...............e
0000020: 6e64 6f66 6669 6c65 0a                   ndoffile.
```

It appears that a byte is missing (0x10).

What am I missing here?

--- Update

Changing the test() function to:

```
def test():
    pipe = sp.Popen( ["test.sh"], stdin=sp.PIPE)
    data = "".join([chr((s)%16+1) for s in range(0,32)])
    os.write(pipe.stdin.fileno(), data)
    pipe.stdin.write("endoffile")
```

Seems to solve that.
It seems to be related to having chr(0) sent to pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range()` is right side exclusive.

`range(0, 33)` is `[0, ..., 32]`, probably because this way you can `range(0, len(sequence))` without off-by-one errors.

Since `32 % 17 == 15 == 0x0f`, the byte `'\x10'` you are expecting was never part of the list in the first place.

**Edit 1:**
Also missing from the output are the zero characters `'\x00'`. If you use `VALUE=$(cat)` the output of `cat` is subject to processing by the shell.

SingleUnix/POSIX seems to be silent on the matter. It is however clear, that you cannot have `'\0'` as part of a shell variable's value (or name for that matter) since the Unix environment requires both to be [C-style zero terminated strings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getenv.html). I actually would have expected the value of `VALUE` to be an empty string.

**Edit 2**
After some digging, I can say that at least the [`ash` implementation](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/10/bin/sh/expand.c?revision=287752&view=markup#l462) ignores `'\0'` processing backtick-supplied input. Input is read until EOF and null characters are explicitly skipped.

`bash` does the same and even has an explicit (even if commented out) [warning](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n5267) associated with the event.

Comment: dhke - You are correct, however the off-by-one error is to the other side - an entry is missing.
I suspect this is due to sending chr(0) via pipe - it is discarded. Any idea why?

Comment: @sferic I did not even realize that the `\0` was also missing, thanks for reminding me. See edit.

Comment: In the contrived example, a solution would for test.sh to contain the single line of code: `cat >> /tmp/test.txt`.

Comment: The problem is not that the output of `cat` is subject to word-splitting (it isn't), but that the null byte terminates the string prematurely. Shell simply isn't designed to handle arbitrary binary data.

Comment: @chepner Ah right, `=` doesn't do word splitting. This actually makes me more sure that this is simply an undocumented side effect that you cannot rely on in any way.

Comment: I can't find an exact, definitive statement, but I'm pretty sure the POSIX specification requires the null byte to be treated as a string terminator in a parameter value. `cat` can produce a string containing a null byte, but the shell is incapable of storing it in a string. Compare with something like `printf 'abc\0def' | { read -d ''; echo $REPLY; read -d ''; echo $REPLY; }`, which never subjects the null byte to shell expansion or storage; it is only read via standard input and discarded as a separator.

Comment: That why I would expect $VALUE to be `''`, but it isn't. It rather looks like, the string is read until EOF and `strcpy()`ied into the variable value. Since `strcpy(target, "\0")` does exactly nothing, the null seems to simply fall of a cliff. I still think this a side effect of the read-till-eof. However, that could also explain random cut-offs because of buffer size unless the shell is always reading char-by-char.